Is the advertising clause 3 of the BSD-4-Clause overrated?
Note: I think BSD-4-Clause is rightly outdated and rightly not listed by the OSI. This is also not a question about compatibility with other licenses. It is purely about interpreting the advertising clause.

The BSD-4-Clause license and its variants contain clause 3: (emph mine)


All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software must display the following acknowledgement:
This product includes software developed by The Organization.



Now, after reading pieces such as Stallman's The BSD Problem:

... When people put many such programs together ... is a serious
problem. Imagine if a software system required 75 different sentences,
each one naming a different author or group of authors. To advertise
that, you would need a full-page ad.

Or answers on this site that state:

4-clause BSD requires you to acknowledge a third party in your advertising material

My thoughts were: "Oh my. How horrible. This seems unusable. You need to advertise these components, which is totally unpractical."
However, seeing as components under BSD-4-Clause are even used inside the .NET runtime by MS, I re-read the clause carefully:

... advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software must display ...

So, if, and only if, my advertising material is mentioning features or use of this software am I required to also include an acknowledgement.
This seems a trivial problem for most code one would typically include as a library in any software: You normally don't mention that you use that library or it's features in your ad: so no extra acknowledgement is needed either.
Would that be the "accepted" interpretation?
If were to use, say, an UTF-8 library that were under BSD-4-clause, in my commercial app and I don't explicitly mention that my app can read UTF-8, then no additional acknowledgement is required?
Don't get me wrong: I think the ad.clause is still "a" problem, as it causes questions and doubts, and may, under some circumstances really require acknowledgement in ad material. It's just that I don't see this as being a thing for most code or software - certainly not to the amount it gets mentioned.

@user20574 - which would be totally fine, imho. Advertisements which list features have so many asterisks nowadays, nobody would raise an eyebrow :-)

I don't know whether I agree with your analysis, but I think it misses the point.
The major problem with the advertising clause, as I see it, isn't that it requires people to make certain statements in certain circumstances; the major problem is that such a requirement is incompatible with other free licences, specifically copyleft licences.  BSD4 requires that you place this obligation on your downstream recipients, and (eg) GPLv3 s7 forbids you from doing exactly that.  This means the code is a lot less useful in terms of what it can and can't be combined with.
Even if the requirement was very hard to trigger - suppose it required that you sing the Berkeley song, but only on alternate Boxing Days, and then only when distributing the software while wearing a yellow tutu - it would still be incompatible.
Edit: you've clarified that you're only interested in combining BSD4 code with permissively-licensed code, so the above doesn't concern you.
That given, I am unconvinced by your analysis.  You assume that in clause 3, this software applies (in your example) only to the BSD4-licensed library.
But if the FSF's approach to linking and copyright derivatives is correct (which isn't a done deal, but it's my belief that it's correct), the entire work is now a modified version of the original library.  Given the preamble to clause 1 and its reference to use of [this software] with or without modification, it seems to me that the correct interpretation of this software in clause 3 is the piece of software currently being distributed, which would cast the net of clause 3 much more widely than you suppose.
I concede that the point is capable of argument, and depending on the calibre of your lawyers your interpretation might well prevail.  But it's not, to my mind, a done deal, and I think you would be foolish to rely on it without getting a formal legal opinion.

Yes, I do agree wrt. the incompatibility with copyleft licenses, thats why I put a note in there. I agree it's problematic, but only when mixing with some copyleft licenses not in general.

So your question is specifically about the issue(s) involved in using BSD-4 code in a permissively-licensed project?

Yes, permissively licensed or a commercially released project. No copyleft.

OK, see edit above.

Thanks for that clarification. As I noted in my OP, MSFT (and possibly Apple) lawyers seem to think BSD-4-Clause is OK, given it's usage in if_media.h. Your arguments are certainly a valuable perspective.

Yes, and they've got Very Expensive Lawyers, so they can afford to take that line (see "capable of argument").  You should probably act according to the size and ferocity of your legal department!
